# Получение доступа к службе кластера

Tags: .net, c#

Доброе утро:)!
кое как удалось получить и разобраться как достучаться до служб удаленного компьютера, но возник еще один вопрос:
-имеется некий удаленные сервер состоящий из несколько компов объединенных в кластер, необходимо получить доступ к службам этого кластера, к сожалению пока ничего не нашел, а при доступе через `WMI` и класс `WIN32` получаю доступ только к службам самих компов. 
попробовал по совету с другого форума через `Failover Cluster Provider Reference`
вот получившийся код:

```
ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("select * from MSCluster_Service");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();
foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in queryCollection)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", queryObj["Status"]);
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", queryObj["Name"]);
}
```

просто все примеры которые нашел по ссылкам, они на C++, а я до него пока не дошел и немного не догоняю те примеры...
но в данном моем случае что тут не так, соединение проходит, запрос вроде правильный и я так понимаю по нему должно нам предоставить массив служб, которые и выводим `foreach`, но почему-то  выдает ошибку :

1. когда в пошаговой обработке отрабатываешь и наводишь на значение `queryCollection`, то уже пишет `System.Management.ManagementExeption`
2. а при начале цикла форич, даже в тело не входит и выдает ошибку сразу на условии выдает: `Invalid class`

Подскажите, пожалуйста!